# Edit global variable's default values permanently

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I saved some values as global variables. I can edit these variables. After the program restarts, all values normally revert to their old default values. I would like to save edited values as new defaults. Is it possible in Flutter/Dart ?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to save the values of global variables using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi Yes,Thanks a lot! This is  what I am looking for :)

Comment: Happy to help, I will also write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `SharedPreferences` package to your `pubspec.yaml'.
Link: [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Step 1:
Get an instance of `SharedPreferences`:

```
final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Step 2:
Save your value using the following methods:

```
sharedPreferences.setString(key, value); // To store a string value
sharedPreferences.setBool(key, value); // To store a bool value
sharedPreferences.setDouble(key, value); // To store a double value
sharedPreferences.setInt(key, value); // To store a int value
sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, value); // To store a string list
```

Step 3:
In order to get the value from `SharedPreferences`, you can use the following methods:

```
sharedPreferences.getString(key); // To get a string value
sharedPreferences.getBool(key); // To get a bool value
sharedPreferences.getDouble(key); // To get a double value
sharedPreferences.getInt(key); // To get a int value
sharedPreferences.getStringList(key); // To get a string list
```

Comment: When I got functions to get sharedPreferences values,I got error about "Flutter: 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"  .I use StatefulWidget. How can I solve this ? Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Can you please describe it in more detail or maybe create a question? Also please add code describing the issue.

Comment: I create a question and shared code there. "How can SharedPreferences value be showed in Flutter/Dart?" This is the question. Thanks